# unwind to master not working in master detail template in xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to get back to the master controller from the detail controller in Xcode 7 iOS 8.3 (iPhone) using an unwind segue triggered by a Done button in my navigation bar, which is set up and properly connected. However, the Master button of the nav controller overlays the Done button. I haven't found a way to trigger the unwind segue in the master controller to load data passed back from the detail controller. Putting a breakpoint in the segue code and clicking on the Master button never hits the breakpoint. How can I get the data back from the detail controller? The Apple tutorial loads data FROM the master TO the detail. I want to do the reverse.

Here is the code for the unwind:

```
 -(IBAction) unwindToMaster: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
    TimerDetailViewController *source = segue.sourceViewController;
    NSLog(@"unwind to master");
    self.timerItem =source.timerItem;
}
```